# Oracle SQL Order By Alphabetical THEN Numeric

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle Business Intelligence (OTBI), what ORDER BY query can I use to sort a column by Alphabet first and then Numerics?

E.g.

```
|---------------------|
|  Expenditure Type   |    
|---------------------|
|   111 Contractors   |       
|---------------------|
|   112 Payroll       |
|---------------------|
|   Annual Leave      |
|---------------------|
|   Christmas Leave   |
|---------------------|
```

And I want it to bring back:

```
|---------------------|
|  Expenditure Type   |    
|---------------------|
|    Annual Leave     |       
|---------------------|
|    Christmas Leave  |
|---------------------|
|    111 Contractors  |
|---------------------|
|    112 Payroll      |
|---------------------|
```

Comment: Something like that : `ORDER  BY regexp_substr(col_name, '[^0-9].*$') nulls last
          ,regexp_substr(col_name, '(\d+)') nulls last;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at my example:

```
with t as (select 'Expenditure Type' as a from dual
union all
select '111 Contractors' from dual
union all
select '112 Payroll' from dual
union all
select 'Annual Leave' from dual
union all
select 'Christmas Leave' from dual)

select * 
from (
    select a, 
                 DECODE(replace(replace(translate(UPPER(a),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','##########################'),'#'),' '),NULL,'ALPHABET','NUMBER') as typ
    from t
)
order by typ
```

Answer (score 0):

the difference in behaviour that you're seeing is probably because of different NLS_SORT parameter setting. Consider:

SQL> `select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter='NLS_SORT';`

PARAMETER                      VALUE

---

NLS_SORT                       BINARY

SQL> `SELECT * FROM my_data order by title;`

### TITLE

321
Abc
Def

SQL> `alter session set nls_sort=french;`

Session altered

SQL> `SELECT * FROM my_data order by title;`

### TITLE

Abc
Def
321